# python using iteration to create a single row of values vs many rows of values from CouchDB

Tags: python, couchdb

I have some code that iterates through 'Documents' in couchDB

```
for docid in db:
    test = db.get(docid)
    try:
        type = test['type']
    except:
        type = "dontTestMe"

    if type == 'file':
        fileName = test['AliasName']
        fileID = test['fileid']
        testName = None

    if type == 'job':
        testName = test['testname']
        stStart = time.strptime(time.ctime(test['teststart']))
        stStop = time.strptime(time.ctime(test['testfinish']))
        difStart = datetime.datetime(stStart.tm_year, stStart.tm_mon, stStart.tm_mday, stStart.tm_hour, stStart.tm_min, stStart.tm_sec)
        difStop = datetime.datetime(stStop.tm_year, stStop.tm_mon, stStop.tm_mday, stStop.tm_hour, stStop.tm_min, stStop.tm_sec)
        diff = difStop - difStart

    print fileName, testName, diff
```

My result is

```
Filename Test1 DurationOfTest
Filename Test2 DurationOfTest
Filename Test3 DurationOfTest
etc...
```

What I want is

```
FileName Test1 Duration Test2 Duration Test3 Duration etc...
```

How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print fileName, testName, diff,
```

notice the trailing **,**

Comment: +1 the trailing comma indicates no newline should be appended.

Comment: That was my first intuition as well, but it looks like the `Filename` (a) shouldn't be repeated, but (b) can also potentially change within the loop itself, so I thought maybe more clarification would be good

Comment: If i add the trailing comma then the result would be "filename, test, diff, test, diff, test, diff, filename test, diff, test, diff" wouldnt it?  I do need the newline, but only when the type = file, that should start a newline.

Comment: This did it, but I had to make a couple of changes.  I had to add a print "" and print fileName, to the type = file section then the type = job section is just prtin testname, diff.